# function and variable "chicken or the egg" scenario

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm making a simple program to run in C++ to do ffmpeg for me, but I have the problem of needing certain variables defined in the "main", but the function needs to be above main to be ready to be used. what can I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int convert()
{
    int operation;
    switch(operation){
        case '1':

        case '2':

        case '3':

        case '4':
            ;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    std::string formatIn;
    std::string FormatOut;
    std::string confirm;
    cout << "select format that file is currently in: mp3, gp3, mp4, flv" << endl;
    cin >> formatIn;
    cout << "original format = " << formatIn << endl;
    cout << "choose your target format: mp3, gp3, mp4, flv" << endl;
    cin >> FormatOut;
    cout << "selected format = " << FormatOut << endl;
    cout << "proceed? ";
    cin >> confirm;
    if(confirm == "yes"){
    cout << "proceeding with operation:" << endl;
    convert();
    }
    else{
            if(confirm == "no"){
            cout << "canceling,,," << endl;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass arguments from a function to another, you can wrap the function and the "common" variables in a class or you could use global  variables. So there are plenty of solutions at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the function a parameter:

```
int convert(int operation)
{
    switch(operation){
```

Then pass it an argument in `main`:

```
int operation = ....
int c = convert(operation);
```

Comment: I dont quite get it, what is the int convert(int operation)?

Comment: @user3426923 It is the function parameter, as suggested by my answer. If you don't know what that is, you need to learn the basics of C++.

Comment: I know its the parameter, I'm not THAT big of a noob. what I'm wondering is how that helps me take the variables from int main().

Comment: @user3426923 You pass an argument when you call the function, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I honestly dont get how I can transfer ALL of the variables back to the function. what I AM getting is well, pretty much nothing.